# jQuery cycle not working on Safari and Chrome

Tags: jquery, cycle

I am having an odd issue which only seems to occur on Safari and Chrome. I have created a slideshow using the jQuery cycle plugin and I am getting this error when using Safari or Chrome:

[cycle] 1  - img slide not loaded, requeueing slideshow:  http://www.blahblahblah.co.uk/images/commercial_main.png 0 0

Here is my code:

```
<div id="banner_wrapper">
        <div id="main_banner_shadow">
            <div id="main_banner">
                <div class="buttons">

                </div>
                <div class="banner_image">
                    <img class="commercial_main" src="/images/commercial_main.png" />
                    <img class="domestic_main"  src="/images/domestic_main.png" />
                    <img class="kitchens_main"  src="/images/kitchens_main.jpg" />
                    <img class="build_main"  src="/images/build_main.jpg" />
                    <img class="Renovation"  src="/images/Renovation.jpg" />                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$('.buttons a:contains("1")').html("COMMERCIAL");
$('.buttons a:contains("2")').html("DOMESTIC");
$('.buttons a:contains("3")').html("KITCHENS & BEDROOMS");
$('.buttons a:contains("4")').html("NEW BUILDS/EXTENSIONS");
$('.buttons a:contains("5")').html("RENOVATION");
```

I can't seem to get rid of this problem. Does anybody know why this is occurring?

Comment: Is the image url definitely correct?

Comment: Yes it is. I click it and it takes me to the correct image.

Comment: Strange - it looks fine.  Can you remove the first 2 images and try it with just jpegs?

Comment: I tried that and it still comes up with an error but on a different image. Really odd.

Comment: Is your cycle call in a `document.ready()` function?

Comment: Yes it is. Can't work this out.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I managed to fix this error. I needed to set a width and height on the images in the markup. Hope this helps!

Comment: Strange.  I use jQuery cycle a lot and never had to do that.  Well if it fixes your problem then it's all good :)

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem, but solved it by putting the width on the actual slideshow container. I need the images to resize responsively so I was relieved to find that solution.